# How to upload multiple pictures to Volusion through API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, httparty, volusion

This is my Volusion item insert method, which relies on the HTTParty gem for rails. It works for posting items without photos, and posting items with a single photos by using the `<PhotoURL_Large>` and `<PhotoURL_Small>` XML tags.

```
def self.post_volusion_item(hide_product, product_code, product_name, product_description, availability, custom_field1, custom_field2, enable_options_inv_control, free_shipping_item, height, length, width, metatag_description, metatag_title, photo_alt_text, photo_xml, product_category, product_price, product_weight, metatag_keywords)
  encrypted_password = ENV['VOLUSION_PASSWORD']
  post_url = "https://WEBSITE-HERE/net/WebService.aspx?Login=LOGIN-HERE&EncryptedPassword=#{encrypted_password}&Import=Insert"
  body = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><Volusion_API><Products><HideProduct>#{hide_product}</HideProduct><ProductCode>#{product_code}</ProductCode><ProductName>#{product_name}</ProductName><ProductDescription>#{product_description}</ProductDescription><Availability>#{availability}</Availability><CustomField1>#{custom_field1}</CustomField1><CustomField2>#{custom_field2}</CustomField2><EnableOptions_InventoryControl>#{enable_options_inv_control}</EnableOptions_InventoryControl><FreeShippingItem>#{free_shipping_item}</FreeShippingItem><Height>#{height}</Height><Length>#{length}</Length><Width>#{width}</Width><METATAG_Description>#{metatag_description}</METATAG_Description><METATAG_Title>#{metatag_title}</METATAG_Title><Photo_AltText>#{photo_alt_text}</Photo_AltText><PhotoURL_Large>#{photo_url_large}</PhotoURL_Large><PhotoURL_Small>#{photo_url_small}</PhotoURL_Small><ProductCategory>#{product_category}</ProductCategory><ProductPrice>#{product_price}</ProductPrice><ProductWeight>#{product_weight}</ProductWeight><METATAG_Keywords>#{metatag_keywords}</METATAG_Keywords></Products></Volusion_API>"

  post(post_url, body: body)
end
```

I can not find any documentation that gives an example with multiple photos in the item. I have tried duplicating the calls. Example: `<PhotoURL_Large>img1</PhotoURL_Large><PhotoURL_Small>img1</PhotoURL_Small><PhotoURL_Large>img2</PhotoURL_Large><PhotoURL_Small>img2</PhotoURL_Small>`

This resulted in no images uploading.

I am realizing the the PhotoURL is not related to the urls of the item's photos, but only tied to the data in Volusion's add item form.

Can someone point me in the right direction for accessing the true photo urls for volusion items?

Answer (score 0):

In Volusion, PhotoURL_Small and PhotoURL_Large are alternate image URLs that can either point to an internal or external location. Volusion only provides one of each for each product code which will be used by the product in place of any loaded image. So if you populate any of the above two fields for that product it will use that URL in place of any image uploaded via the image manager or any images directly uploaded via FTP. There is no provision in the software for additional PhotoURL_Small and PhotoURL_Large images.

Here is an excellent explanation of image file structure.

[Image structure](http://www.brandlabs.us/kb/much-ado-about-photos-in-volusion)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and the documentation link. Would you agree then that the only solution for uploading items with multiple photos from a custom app would be to post the item with an API call, and then FTP the photos with the correct file names to vspfiles/photos?

Comment: You don't need to post anything to Volusion. You just need to upload the images with the correct product code prefix and suffix as shown in the documentation I previously linked to. Your products will automatically be shown if the image file is correctly named. This goes for multiple alternate images and swatch images as well as all others shown in the documentation.